# I don't understand why "Null pointer Exception" in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

in my C# lives class I have a class attribute:
public int life = 0;
and in my C# loose class (so, another script), I want to access to my life attribute of my lives class, but i don't succeed, how to do it ?

When I do

```
var lv = new lives ();
int lv1 = lv.life;
```

It shows me that Unity does not allow. I MUST use GetComponent

so I do with get component

```
var lv = gameObject.GetComponent<lives> ();
int lv1 = lv.life;
```

And I have a null pointer exception, so it is not understandable ?

Comment: You have a `NullReferenceException` (`NullPointerException` is in Java) and it sounds like `gameObject` is null... you haven't shown us where you believe you're initializing that.

Answer (score 1):

You don't use `new` to create a reference to `MonoBehaviour` derived classes.

The `GetComponent` call needs to be associated to the gameobject that class is actually on like this:

```
public GameObject objectWithLives;    // populate this e.g. via inspector

...

Lives lives = objectWithLives.GetComponent<Lives>();    // NOTE: Always start classes with an uppercase!
```

Saying

```
Lives lives = gameObject.GetComponent<Lives>();
```

only works if that script is on the same object as this script.

You don't need to actually store the variable of that other script into a local variable (at least if they shall refer to the same value, otherwise you can do that). Just say something like

```
lives.life = 5;
```

If that class (script) actually is not meant to be on a gameobject then you don't derive from `MonoBehaviour` (that's not a must, only if you need stuff from MonoBehaviour and/or want to put the script on an object).
If you don't derive from MonoBehaviour then you use the standard way of referencing the class by saying `new Lives()`.